# How to run TypeScript from local directory instead of global

Tags: typescript

So I have multiple projects each using diff type of TypeScript, so I uninstalled from global and have it local to my project but when I run tsc I get an error of:

```
$ tsc --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

root@DESKTOP-N8OLDFM /cygdrive/c/msweb/studiolite
$
```

and I did add the following to my PATH:

```
/cygdrive/C/msweb/studiolite/node_modules/typescript/bin
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `tsc` using your package manager (Npm, Yarn or whatever you use to manage the packages of your projects). It launches the instance of `tsc` installed in the current project and ignores the globally installed one (i.e. you don't even need to uninstall it).

Comment: @apokryfos - I'd post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: unfortunately I have to run tsc and not npx as I am also using WebStorm, so I need everything in Windows to pickup the local tsc.exe

Comment: @born2net - WebStorm can't either use `npx` or handle this for you? That seems surprising.

Comment: There should be an option to specify where typescript is in webstorm. There is one in PhpStorm and I think those two share a core. Just try searching through the options

Answer (score 6):

You can add an entry to `scripts` in `package.json` to not only run `tsc` but fill in the standard arguments you want, e.g.:

```
"scripts": {
  "tsc": "tsc your args here"
},
```

and then use

```
npm run tsc
```

That will run the one from `node_modules`, not the global one.

For ad-hoc commands, see [apokryfos's `npx` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56566007/157247).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) to run locally installed executables

Example:

```sh
npx tsc --version
```

If your package manager of choice is `yarn` then doing `yarn tsc --version` should also work but that is assuming there is no script named `tsc` in your package.json.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that may work for command line, but I also need WebStorm to pickup the ./node_modules tsc as well.. is there a way to tell everything in the env to pickup tsc from specific path?

Comment: @born2net - I think you may want to ask that as a separate, WebStorm-specific question. The question you asked doesn't mention WebStorm (and *does* show a command line example) and so has attracted generic command-line answers. It wouldn't be appropriate to change the question once it has answers.